# Thunderbird crashes when it first launches. Relaunch it and it's OK. Any solutions?

Tags: crash

When I boot my mid-2012 MacBook Pro running High Sierra, Thunderbird crashes when it first launches. Relaunch it and it's OK. Any solutions?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall Thunderbird? Be careful not to lose any messages you may have stored locally.

Comment: Please attach your crash report.